# div not growing in height when I use percentage (CSS HTML)

Tags: html, css, height, percentage

I've recently been working on something, and I created a div element to contain everything. I made the width 100% and the height 100%. However when I do this, the div is super small and doesn't have any height. It gains height when I use pixels though. Here is my code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #71A048;
  font-family: verdana;
}

.border {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="border"></div>
```

Here it is on CodePen:
https://codepen.io/MAXHACKER/pen/YzwjrbZ

Comment: html, body {height: 100%} or body {height: 100vh}

Comment: That's because its parent containers have no height.
Set the height of your body and html to 100% for example.

Comment: Thanks, I get it now, but is there a way to make it so that when you resize the browser and ect. there will never be overflow and it will size with the screen?